# SSRS 2005 Report - 2 Pages using Lists

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I have a SSRS report that I have been tasked with adding a second page to.  The first page is defined by a list.  I have expanded the body area of the report to house a second list.  Both Lists have a size of 8.5 x 11.

My question is this.

Is this the proper way of adding a second page.  And if it is, how can I make it so the second  page shows up after every record of the first page?'

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood , you want a record to display after each record of the first list.
if yes Try to Do the Following :

1. Add a new report this will be page two.
2. In the first list page one , add the new report into the list as a sub report.
3. Now after each record in list 1 , you will see a record from page 2.
4. If there are parameters you want to send to sub report from list1 , Right click on     the sub report in list 1, add the proper parameters from list 1 .

Comment: Mostly fixed the error off your outline here.  An added bonus to the whole solution was ensuring you pass the right value to the subreport.  I was passing a parameter when I needed to send a row value of the main report.